# Spring Maven Project - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sources must not be empty

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to start up a Spring Boot application but it is failing to start up. This is my stack trace:

```
11:27:59.772 [main] DEBUG 
org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included 
patterns for restart : []
11:27:59.775 [main] DEBUG 
org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded 
patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring- 
boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, 
 /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, 
 /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
11:27:59.776 [main] DEBUG 
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs 
for reloading : [file:/C:/Users/Bobi/Documents/workspace-sts- 
3.9.2.RELEASE/springproject/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v2.0.0.M7)

2018-03-18 11:28:00.308  INFO 5048 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting SpringApplication 
v2.0.0.M7 on DESKTOP-MFS6ORP with PID 5048 
(C:\Users\Bobi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring- 
boot\2.0.0.M7\spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar started by Bobi in 
C:\Users\Bobi\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE\springproject)
2018-03-18 11:28:00.313  INFO 5048 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling 
back to default profiles: default
2018-03-18 11:28:01.410 ERROR 5048 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sources must not be empty
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:450) ~[spring- 
core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:381) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.main(SpringApplication.java:1261) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher 
.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
```

This is my main class:

```
package com.example.a;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App  
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>a</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>a</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am using Spring Tool Suite and I created the project by File->New->Maven Project. I added some dependencies and added the `SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);` row in the main class and that's it.
I tried other similar suggestions on StackOverflow but nothing worked for me. What do I have to do or change in order to get the application to start up correctly?

Comment: The given pom file and the output does not fit together cause in the output you have references to cloud in M7 in your pom there is nothing about that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I don't know how I was running the project before, but I just went *Right Click->Run As->Spring Boot App* and it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, when I was running it as a spring boot app, it showed the error, but when I ran it as Java Application from Right-click-> run as -> Java Application, it worked completely fine.